# Как реализовать передвижение персонажа в играх от третего лица на unity3d?

Tags: c#, unity3d

Можете обьяснить как реализовать без стандарного ассета?
Есть стандарное передвижение через CharacterController. Как сделать чтобы персонаж бегал в сторону где смотрит камера, а не только по двум направление xy.

Comment: Используй camera.transform

Comment: Вопрос слишком общий и объемный. Вы пытались что-то сами написать? Нет? Стандартный ассет занимает пару сотен строк, вы хотите, чтобы какой-то смельчак все это построчно переписал и откомментировал под ваши нужды?

Comment: Передвижение уже есть , но персонаж двигаеться по осьям мира , а нужно в ось движение был по направлению камеры.

Comment: Приведите здесь свой код, чтобы было понятнее, что у вас уже есть)

Comment: При перемещении используйте не глобальные оси а playerda.transform.forward. Думаю это может помочь вам

Comment: Получаешь угол Y персонажа или камеры (смотря какое поведение нужно). Вычисляешь синус и косинус, умножаешь x на синус z на косинус. Если движемся в противоположную сторону - ставим знак минус.